# Splash intent is not working Android

Tags: android

After creating my main activity now I am adding splash screen but the splash intent is not opening the main activity.

After editing the manifest file

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Also, post your intent code. You say it's not opening the main activity, so the errors is probably in the intent code.

Comment: Post your code directly.

Answer (score 1):

define **.mainActivity** outside **.splash** activity in ***manifest file***
like below

cut

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

and paste above

```
<activity android:name=".CustomList"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your manifest file like this

declare your `MAinActivity` outside the `splash activity` tag like this

```
<application>
   <activity android:name=".splash" />
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
   <activity android:name=".customlist" />
</application>
```

Comment: unfortunately, app has stopped after display the splash screen

Comment: can your share your crash log